# how do you use ftps in RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I need to get some files from the ftp servers. In my old instance I was using sftp and it was working. I found out that this instance dont support sftp.

This was my syntax to get sftp using RCurl:

```
url<-c("sftp://192.168.101.3/data/files.csv")
x<-getURL(url, userpwd="userid:passwd", connecttimeout=60)
```

I tried to replace sftp with ftps, did not work. Does anybody know the RCurl ftps syntax?

I also did this:

```
url<-c("ftps://userid:passwd@/192.168.101.3/data/files.csv")
x<-getURL(url, connecttimeout=60)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

Comment: Did you see what protocols are supported in your version `library(RCurl); curlVersion()`. In mine, `sftp` is not, but `ftps` is

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yes I do see ftps, I tried ftps, I get couldnt connect to host. what would be they syntax for ftps using Rcurl?